# SSO implementation using djangosaml2

Tags: python, django, single-sign-on, saml

Experts,
I am a novice in implementing the SSO (SAML) for a django application. I want to use SAML integration using djangosaml2/pysaml2. Any best tutorial with example is very much helpful.

Comment: Any solution found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing : What you have tried ?

Before asking your question you should tell community what you tried and you caught up with some issues.

However you are new here I would like to answer it for you.

There are many SAML2 packages are available on pypi please go through it.

One of them is [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/djangosaml2/)

You have to get the xml from your IDP (Identity provider) and you have to ask your IDP to configure your metadata in IDP system.

The above library will help you to generate your metadata.Please follow the steps given in documentation

Try and then if you get some issue do let us know.

Comment: I read the djangosaml2 documentation page. I didnt digest the content when i posted this question. Now, i am in a comfortable position in implementing this. I understood that djangosaml2 helps in integrating the pysaml with the django app. I was stuck in generating the service provider xml,i didnt know how to do that. I read the pysaml2 documentation and generated the sp.xml using sp_conf.py and make_metadata. After reading your answer, i understood we can also generate the metadata using djangosaml2 which is available at /saml2/metadata as per documentations. Thanks @burning. Working on it.

Comment: am getting 'SPConfig' object has no attribute '_sp_authn_requests_signed' error when i try to access '/saml2/login' . i searched if there is anything available on the web, but no luck. I added a key/pair 'authn_assertions_signed':'true' in settings.py too. But still i get the same error

Comment: put this under sp in  your settings.py             "authn_requests_signed": "true",

Comment: @Venu: Also, the `_sp_authn_requests_signed` error should be gone in the next release as [it's now fixed on `master`](https://github.com/knaperek/djangosaml2/commit/3e2458170f4e01eb4d51453cc642f7f96ed4d1c0)

Comment: @Venu - wasn't me! =)

Comment: i have posted another  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36448401/djangosaml2-not-able-to-update-additional-attributes-to-inbuilt-django-user-mode) for extending the user model. Am facing issues in setting the SAML_PROFILE_MODULE for a extended user model. What should be the path for the extended user model?

Comment: Hey, @Venu how to generate sp metadata from djangosaml2?

Comment: @ShivinAgarwal IDP will provide you there Metadata . You need not to generate it . You have to just save it

Comment: @burning Got it, Thank you so much.