# djangosaml2 not able to update additional attributes to inbuilt django User Model

Tags: django, django-models, saml-2.0

1. I have added the SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING in the settings.py with the below details. They are available with the inbuilt User model. The unknown user is getting created but additional attributes are not updated.

   ```
   SAML_CREATE_UNKNOWN_USER = True

   SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING = {
       'uid': ('username', ),
       'mail': ('email', ),
       'cn': ('first_name', ),
       'sn': ('last_name', ),
   }
   ```
2. Also, I have extended user model. I read the documentation that we can use SAML_PROFILE_MODULE. I have an app called runbook. I defined a model called SamUser which is extended version of inbuilt User. Now how should i update the variable SAML_PROFILE_MODULE?

I tried doing , `SAML_PROFILE_MODULE = runbook.models.SamUser`, it says module object doesn't have attribute models. Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: can anybody help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING = {
    'uid': ('username', ),
    'mail': ('email', ),
    'cn': ('first_name', ),
    'sn': ('last_name', ),
}

replace above with 

SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING = {
    'uid': ('username', ),
    'mail': ('email', ),
    'first_name': ('first_name', ),
    'last_name': ('last_name', ),
}
```

Comment: i have the extended User model already implemented. My requirement is  via djangosaml2, when the user logs in using the SSO, a non-existing user should be created using inbuilt User model, which is happening(becoz of SAML_CREATE_UNKNOWN_USER = True). But only username is populated.. The other fields like email, last_name first_name are not getting updated. Even i have the SAML_ATTRIBUTE_MAPPING set.

Comment: 2. Which is my main requirement, I want djangosaml2 to use the extended Usermodel for creating the non-existing users or new users. I tried to do it using the variable "SAML_PROFILE_MODULE = runbook.models.SamUser" but it dint work. it says module object doesn't have attribute model

Comment: it is not working with the updated mapping too. I see the variable 'ava' in the SAML response is empty. but when i track the SAML response using [ SAML tracer ] (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/) i am able to see the mentioned attributes.

Comment: print user object and she does it have that value or not

Comment: yep, user object exists.

Comment: i have used ** to protect some data. this is the output of session_info and session_info['name_id].text    {'authn_info'[('urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport', [], '2016-04-11T06:24:56Z')], 'name_id': <saml2.saml.NameID object at 0x7fcce066fa50>, 'not_on_or_after': 1460359796, 'session_index': 'id-iQDjadk9DlpaMWlVLKHPGGs488U-', 'came_from': u’/runbook/', 'ava': {}, 'issuer': ‘********’}
User : sam

Comment: Per the [code](https://github.com/sdelements/djangosaml2/blob/master/djangosaml2/backends.py) i see, attributes are populated based from session_info['ava']. but in the SAML response i see that ava is empty. Not sure why it is empty. digging more on this.

Comment: i don't know what is your situation I  was also getting this error but I fixed it by doing above.